# How to draw badge and add it to image in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am having notification icon and i want to show that icon with badge while new notifications are available or else i need to show only notification icon.

in my case i need to draw a red badge and add it on existing icon image and pass that to other custom component(own component) which is accepting image

Please Refer screenshot 1 for - screenshot is notifcation icon which i have.

Refer screenshot 2 for  expected one when new notification available, i want to draw badge and add it to existing icon.

[image: This first screenshot is notifcation icon which i have]

[image: This second screenshot is expected one when new notification available, i want to draw badge and add it to existing icon]

Thanks in advance

Comment: UIKit or SwiftUI? What have you tried? `Circle` for SwiftUI or a simple `UIView` with a corner radius for UIKit are good starting points.  You don't need to add the badge to the image. Just draw it on top of the image view

Comment: Hi @Paulw11, i am expecting in UIKit

Comment: Then I suggest you create a `UIView`, set its colour to red, constrain it to have an equal width and height and set its corner radius to half of the width/height. Then position this view on the top corner of your UIImageView.

Comment: Use the SF Symbol named bell.badge. It supports multicolor so you should be able to make the dot red in color.

Comment: Hi @HangarRash, SF Symbol bell icon is bit different so that i can’t use that, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlertWithBadgeView is a view which has two imageViews. The *alertImageView* is used for a background image and the *badgeImageView* is used for badge image.

```
class AlertWithBadgeView: UIView {
    
    var alertImageView: UIImageView!
    var badgeImageView: UIImageView!
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("don't use the view from within storyboards or xibs")
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        createView()
    }
    
    private func createView() {
        _ = {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            addSubview(imageView)
            imageView.frame = bounds
            imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            alertImageView = imageView
        }()
        _ = {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            addSubview(imageView)
            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
                imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
                imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
                imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            ])
            badgeImageView = imageView
        }()
    }
}
```

Basic creation and configuration can be done from *cellForRow(at:)* method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    
    let alert = AlertWithBadgeView()
    alert.alertImageView.image = .init(systemName: "bell.badge")
    alert.badgeImageView.image = .init(systemName: "circle.fill")
    cell.addSubview(alert)
    alert.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        cell.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.centerYAnchor),
        cell.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.leadingAnchor, constant: -20),
        alert.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
        alert.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
    ])
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Above solution is fine but in my case is different, we are having custom components which is we developed as a different framework, we consume required UI components, in here component is accepting only image , we can’t use as imageview and all, so that is possible to add badge to an existing image icon and pass it to that component variable as a image, in new notification scenario i need to pass image icon with badge